# how to access to a NTFS mounted disk from terminal

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have found a lot of tutorial on the web that how to mount a NTFS drive but I do not find any tutorial how to access a drive from terminal after mounting.
Like what to write to get access after writing "cd X"?
what should be X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maruf , you said you have mounted that partition. If you mounted a NTFS partition then you are definitely going to mount that partition at a Mount Point.

Assume that mount point `/mnt/X` , then do as

`cd /mnt/X`  , So right now you are in NTFS partition and do what you are meant to do.

If this is not you are expecting to read then elaborate your issue and pop more information in box.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get your answer. Actually in ubuntu it's been done automatically. I just have to see the mounting point by writing command "lsblk" which shows tree table of the harddisk and then write command "mount" then I can see the mount point for each disk. Thanks to you I learned the term mount point from you by which I can google and found my ans.